# Is RichEditBox in WinUI3 support ScrollView_Changeing event?

Tags: richeditbox

The RichEditBox controll in WinUI3 has scrollbar, but I don't know how to handle the scrollbar's changing event, and how to set position of the scrollbar.
In the visual tree I can see that RichEditBox contains a scrollviewer, can I get the scrollviewer and set its event handler?

Comment: Please dont ask a question inside an answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a ScrollViewer to wrap the RichEditBox, deal with the ScrollViewer's event, I can get the scroll offset of RichEditBox. That match my question.

But, there's a nother question, how can I do the same thing for webview2? It dosn't work for webview2.

Comment: It's good that you found a solution to your initial question but you shouldn't ask questions within an answer. Instead as a new question if really necessary